# I am trying to print out the highest bidder in my list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to loop through my list of dictionaries and print out the highest bidder in my list of dictionaries.  In a for loop with python is 'i' not automatically an integer?

Example : for i in dictionary:
Does i not equal  0, 1, 2 so on?

```
bidders = [
{
  "name": "nicholas",
  "bid": 12,
},
{
  "name": "jack",
  "bid": 69,
},
]

for i in bidders:
        bid = bidders[i]["bid"]
        name = bidders[i]["name"]
        
        if bid > bid:
            print(f"Congratulations {name}! Your bid of ${bid} wins!")
        else:
            print(f"Congratulations {name}! Your bid of ${bid} wins!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) to range through a list and get the current index. Fixing your `for` loop, it would look like this:

```
for idx, _ in enumerate(bidders):
    bid = bidders[idx]["bid"]
    name = bidders[idx]["name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, since you are not calling the range function i is not default a integer. Leonardo's answer looks more correct, however what I wrote down below would also work.

```
bidders = [
    {
      "name": "nicholas",
      "bid": 12,
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "bid": 69,
    },
]

maxBid = -1
maxBidName = "";

for i in range(0, len(bidders)):

    bid = bidders[i]["bid"]
    name = bidders[i]["name"]

    if bid > maxBid:
        maxBid = bid
        maxBidName = name
        

print(f"Congratulations {maxBidName}! Your bid of ${maxBid} wins!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you’re looking for is `bid = i[‘bid’]`. `i` in this case is simply part of the dictionary. So for each entry, you want the value of `’bid’`.

Answer (score 0):

there are few mistakes, i think this will works

```
bidders = [
{
  "name": "nicholas",
  "bid": 12,
},
{
  "name": "jack",
  "bid": 69,
},
]

highestBid = 0
highestBidData = {}

for i in bidders:
    if i['bid'] > highestBid:
        highestBid = i['bid']
        highestBidData = i
        
print("Congratulations {0}! Your bid of {1} `enter code 
here`wins!".format(highestBidData['name'],highestBidData['bid']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bidders = [
{
  "name": "nicholas",
  "bid": 12,
},
{
  "name": "jack",
  "bid": 69,
},
]

maxBidder = max(bidders, key=lambda x:x['bid'])

print("Congratulations {}! Your bid of {} wins!".format(maxBidder['name'],maxBidder['bid']))
```

Answer (score 0):

> In a for loop with python is 'i' not automatically an integer?
>
> Example : for i in dictionary: Does i not equal 0, 1, 2 so on?

No

A very easy way to find out what it is is simply:

```
for i in bidders:
    print(i)
    print(type(i))
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'nicholas', 'bid': 12}
<class 'dict'>
{'name': 'jack', 'bid': 69}
<class 'dict'>
```